# $((n-1)^{0.5})/(((n+1)^2)-1)$ Is the sum convergent?, why or why not?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, divergent-series

> $$\frac{(n-1)^{0.5}}{(n+1)^2-1}$$

Sorry I dont know how to to do sub or superscripts.
I would like a step by step method please, thanks.

Comment: Ratio test didnt work out, Rot test would not work on a series like this, cant think of anything to compare it too. I dont know how to integrate it and dont know what to compare with it for quotient or limit comparison test

Comment: @lexist Can't think of anything to compare it to? The numerator has "degree" $1/2$, and the denominator has degree $2$. $$2 - \dfrac 1 2 = \dfrac 3 2$$ That's a good hint.

Answer (score 2):

It is convergent. To see this, use *equivalents*:

- $(n-1)^{1/2}\sim_\infty n^{1/2}$
- $(n+1)^2-1\sim_\infty n^2$

Hence $\;\dfrac{(n-1)^{1/2}}{(n+1)^2-1}\sim_\infty\dfrac{n^{1/2}}{n^2}=\dfrac1{n^{3/2}}$, which converges.

Comment: Thank you, but is this sufficient as a proper mathematical proof?

Comment: If you've seen equivalents, there's a theorem about this, for series *with positive terms*: if their terms are equivalent at infinity, they both converge or both diverge. Probably, you should add the latter is Riemann series with exponent $>1$.